# Trying to post additional values with serialize() removes + signs from value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have 1 hidden field that has a random token in it for CSRF protection. I am serializing a form and trying to send this field separately like this:

```
data: $( "#profileForm" ).serialize() + "&form_token="+ form_token,
```

For some reason though it leaves out + signs. So, if the token is:

1xy2+80a3

it becomes:

1xy280a3

And for this reason my session variable token doesn't match my form token, because of the missing + sign. If the random token doesn't have a + in it then it works fine. I don't understand why it is removing the + signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `$.param` together with `$.serializeArray` to create the form data

```
data : $.param($("#profileForm").serializeArray()
                                .concat([{name:'form_token', value:'1xy2+80a3'}]
       )),
```

If `data:` is something from jQuery, for instance from `$.ajax`, you can pass the result of `serializeArray` directly, and jQuery will run `$.param` internally for you

```
data : $("#profileForm").serializeArray().concat([{name:'form_token', value:'1xy2+80a3'}],
```

Answer (score 2):

> jQuery [Encode/Decode](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-decode-url-string/) String

```js
var Param1 = '1xy2+80a3'; 
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(Param1);
$("#Encode").text(encoded);

var Param2 = '1xy2%2B80a3';
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(Param2);
$("#Decode").text(decoded);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Encode  String<span><br>
<code id="Encode"></code ><hr>
<span>Decode  String<span><br>
<code  id="Decode"></code>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the encodeURIComponent() method here: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

To actually answer your question, the + character is a reserved character in URIs and will be replaced before transmission.